# Laravel/Ajax Grab Values From Database After Update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an edit form, where an admin can edit book details. Upon submitting this form, the values update in the database, and the page should load the updated values into the form (Without refreshing/reloading the page).

I have the values being entered getting updated in the database fine, but they don't get loaded into the input fields.. My code just grabs the "old" values and sticks them back into the fields..

Just to explain it step-by-step, using "Title" as the field we'll change for the example.
I have a book named "Old Book". I input on the edit form a new title of "New Title". I click the "Submit" button. The page scrolls back to the top (As it should), but the input box displays "Old Title" still. If I then refresh the page (F5), the input box now displays "New Title".

I want the above to happen without having to refresh the page though.

Here's the edit page Javascript/Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#editbook_form').bootstrapValidator(
    {
        feedbackIcons:
        {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields:
        {
            eb_title:
            {
                validators:
                {
                    notEmpty:
                    {
                        message: 'You must enter a book title'
                    }
                }
            },
            eb_insoft:
            {
                validators:
                {
                    notEmpty:
                    {
                        message: 'You must enter a value for In Soft'
                    }
                }
            },
            eb_inhard:
            {
                validators:
                {
                    notEmpty:
                    {
                        message: 'You must enter a value for In Hard'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e)
    {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');


        title = $("#title").val();
        m_keywords = $("#eb_mkeywords").val();
        m_description = $("#eb_mdescription").val();
        description = $("#eb_description").val();
        electronic_price = $("#eb_electronicprice").val();
        audio_price = $("#eb_audioprice").val();
        soft_price = $("#eb_softprice").val();
        hard_price = $("#eb_hardprice").val();
        in_soft = $("#eb_insoft").val();
        in_hard = $("#eb_inhard").val();
        status_id = $("#eb_statusid").val();
        isbn = $("#eb_isbn").val();
        date_published = $("#eb_datepublished").val();
        notes = $("#eb_notes").val();

        console.log("BEFORE AJAX CALL");

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            //url: base_url+"/book/updateBook",
            url: "[[URL::to('book/updateBook')]]",
            dataType : 'json', // expected returned data format.
            data:
            {
                book_id: window.book_id,
                title: title,
                m_keywords: m_keywords,
                m_description: m_description,
                description: description,
                electronic_price: electronic_price,
                audio_price: audio_price,
                soft_price: soft_price,
                hard_price: hard_price,
                in_soft: in_soft,
                in_hard: in_hard,
                status_id: status_id,
                isbn: isbn,
                date_published: date_published,
                notes: notes,
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.valid==true)
                {
                    console.log("DATA VALID IS TRUE");
                    //alert("VALID: " + data.valid + "\nTITLE: " + data.title);


                    $("#edit_err").removeClass('text-danger').addClass('text-success');
                    $("#edit_err").html(data.message);

                    oldInSoft = "";

                    $('#editbook_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
                    $('#editbook_form')[0].reset();

                    //location.reload();
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);

                    //$('#eb_message').html("Book successfully updated!");

                    $('#title').html("[[ $book->title ]]");
                    $('#eb_mkeywords').html("[[ $book->m_keywords ]]");
                    $('#eb_mdescription').html("[[ $book->m_description ]]");
                    $('#eb_description').html("[[ $book->description ]]");
                    $('#eb_electronicprice').html("[[ $book->electronic_price ]]");
                    $('#eb_audioprice').html("[[ $book->audio_price ]]");
                    $('#eb_softprice').html("[[ $book->soft_price ]]");
                    $('#eb_hardprice').html("[[ $book->hard_price ]]");
                    $('#eb_insoft').html("[[ $book->in_soft ]]");
                    $('#eb_inhard').html("[[ $book->in_hard ]]");
                    $('#eb_statusid').html("[[ $book->status_id ]]");
                    $('#eb_isbn').html("[[ $book->isbn ]]");
                    $('#eb_datepublished').html("[[ $book->date_published ]]");
                    $('#eb_notes').html("[[ $book->notes ]]");
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("DATA VALID IS FALSE");
                    $("#edit_err").addClass("text-danger");
                    $("#edit_err").html(data.message);
                }
            },
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                console.log("INSIDE BEFORESEND");
                $("#edit_err").html("Loading...");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the controller:

```
public function updateBook(Request $request)
{
    $valid = false;
    //$data = Input::all();
    //$message = '';

    $id = $request->input('book_id');
    $title = $request->input('title');
    $m_keywords = $request->input('m_keywords');
    $m_description = $request->input('m_description');
    $description = $request->input('description');
    $electronic_price = $request->input('electronic_price');
    $audio_price = $request->input('audio_price');
    $soft_price = $request->input('soft_price');
    $hard_price = $request->input('hard_price');
    $in_soft = $request->input('in_soft');
    $in_hard = $request->input('in_hard');
    $status_id = $request->input('status_id');
    $isbn = $request->input('isbn');
    $notes = $request->input('notes');
    $date_published = $request->input('date_published');


    $valid = DB::table('book')->where('book_id', $id)->update(
        [
            'title' => $title,
            'm_keywords' => $m_keywords,
            'm_description' => $m_description,
            'description' => $description,
            'electronic_price' => $electronic_price,
            'audio_price' => $audio_price,
            'soft_price' => $soft_price,
            'hard_price' => $hard_price,
            'in_soft' => $in_soft,
            'in_hard' => $in_hard,
            'status_id' => $status_id,
            'isbn' => $isbn,
            'date_published' => $date_published,
            'notes' => $notes
        ]
        );

    if($valid) 
    {
        return response()->json(array('valid' => true,'message' => 'Book successfully updated!'));
    } 
    else 
    {
        return response()->json(array('valid' => false,'message' => 'Book not updated, please fix any errors'));
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not updating the old data on the object you are using.
you just create a new variables as below. and send them to the update method.
but you are using the old data from the old object. $book

```
    $id = $request->input('book_id');
    $title = $request->input('title');
    $m_keywords = $request->input('m_keywords');
    $m_description = $request->input('m_description');
    $description = $request->input('description');
    $electronic_price = $request->input('electronic_price');
    $audio_price = $request->input('audio_price');
    $soft_price = $request->input('soft_price');
    $hard_price = $request->input('hard_price');
    $in_soft = $request->input('in_soft');
    $in_hard = $request->input('in_hard');
    $status_id = $request->input('status_id');
    $isbn = $request->input('isbn');
    $notes = $request->input('notes');
    $date_published = $request->input('date_published');
```

**try update the data at the object
using $this->title = ...
and so on.**

Comment: Using $this in the edit pages success block just gives an error `Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::$title (View: C:\wamp64\www\resources\views\admin\editbook.blade.php)`. Using it in the controller to declare the variables just gives a 500 Internal Server Error `$this->$title = $request->input('title');`